# Is 2-SAT with XOR-relations NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, xor, 2-sat

I'm wondering if there is a polynomial algorithm for "2-SAT with XOR-relations". Both 2-SAT and XOR-SAT are in P, but is its combination?

Example Input:

- 2-SAT part: `(a or !b) and (b or c) and (b or d)`
- XOR part : `(a xor b xor c xor 1) and (b xor c xor d)`

In other words, the input is the following boolean formula:

$$(a \lor \neg b) \land (b \lor c) \land (b \lor d) \land (a \oplus b \oplus \neg c) \land (b \oplus c \oplus d).$$

Example Output: Satisfiable: a=1, b=1, c=0, d=0.

Both the number of 2-SAT clauses and the number of XOR clauses in the input are $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of boolean variables.

Comment: this problem is fairly close, [bitwise xor of vectors to equal a target vector](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/0-1-vector-xor-problem), cstheory.se

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2-SAT-with-XOR-relations can be proven NP-complete by reduction from 3-SAT.  Any 3-SAT clause $$(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3)$$ can be rewritten into the equisatisfiable 2-SAT-with-XOR-relations expression $$(x_1 \lor \overline{y}) \land (y \oplus x_2 \oplus z) \land (\overline{z} \lor x_3)$$ with $y$ and $z$ as new variables.

Comment: All answers seem to be correct or assisting, but I found this one the most elegant (imho).

Comment: Nice answer. It may be worth mentioning that mere equisatisfiability would not be enough here (since the satisfying assignments of the expressions corresponding to all the clauses of a satisfiable CNF might not match), but your rewritten expression actually has a corresponding satisfying assignment for *each* satisfying assignment of the original clause.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't specified the arity of your XOR relations, but like in the usual SAT-to-3SAT reduction, you can always arrange that their arity be at most 3. Now you are in great position to apply [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem), which will tell you whether your problem is in P or NP-complete (these are the only two options). If it turns out to be in P, the next step could be looking at [Allender et al.](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/cspJCSS.pdf), which will let you know how easy your problem is.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the condition that there are $O(n)$ constraints, but you can always add dummy variables to ensure that the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

By [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem#Modern_presentation), this is NP-complete.

Consider the case where all clauses have 2 or 3 literals in them; then we can consider this as a constraint satisfaction problem over a set $\Gamma$ of relations of arity 3.  In particular, the relations $R(x,y,z)$ are the following: $x \lor y$, $x \lor \neg y$, $\neg x \lor \neg y$, $x \oplus y \oplus z$, $x \oplus y \oplus \neg z$.

Now apply Schaefer's dichotomy theorem, in [its modern form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem#Modern_presentation).  Check each of the six operations to see if they are a polymorphism:

- Unary 0: Not a polymorphism of $x \lor y$.
- Unary 1: Not a polymorphism of $\neg x \lor \neg y$.
- Binary AND: Not a polymorphism of $x \lor y$.  (Consider $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$; they both satisfy the relation, but their pointwise-AND $(0,0,0)$ doesn't.)
- Binary OR: Not a polymorphism of $\neg x \lor \neg y$.  (Consider $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$; they satisfy the relation, but $(1,1,0)$ doesn't.)
- Ternary majority: Not a polymorphism of $x \oplus y \oplus z$.  (Consider $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$; they satisfy the relation, but their majority $(0,0,0)$ doesn't.)
- Ternary minority: Not a polymorphism of $x \lor y$.  (Consider $(0,1,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, and $(1,1,0)$; they satisfy the relation, but their minority $(0,0,0)$ doesn't.)

It follows that this problem is NP-complete, even if you restrict all the XOR clauses to be of length at most 3.

---

On the other hand, if all the XOR clauses are restricted to be of length at most 2, then this is in P.  In particular $(x \oplus y)$ is equivalent to $(x \lor y) \land (\neg x \lor \neg y)$, so any such formula is equivalent to a 2SAT formula, whose satisfiability can be determined in polynomial time.