# Why do Shaefer's and Mahaney's Theorems not imply P = NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, p-vs-np

I'm sure someone has thought about this before or immediately dismissed it, but why does Schaefer's dichotomy theory along with Mahaney's theorem on sparse sets not imply P = NP ?

Here's my reasoning:  Create a language $L$ which is equal
to SAT intersected by an infinite decidable sparse set.  Then $L$ must also be
sparse.  Since $L$ it is not trivial, affine, 2-sat, or Horn-sat, by
Shaefer's theorem it must be NP-complete.  But then we have a sparse
NP-complete set so by Mahaney's theorem, P=NP.

Where am I going wrong here?  I suspect that I am misunderstanding/misapplying Shaefer's theorem but I don't see why.

Comment: Closely related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42544/755  (read the answers before trying to understand all of the details of the question; the answers are relatively self-contained)

Comment: have wondered about this myself before thx so much for asking! the trick is that schaefers thm is not actually stating that there are no intermediate languages "between" P/NP, it is more subtle. also, try studying the class NPI, aka NP intermediate, there are many refs on [cstheory.se]. many major problems are "in" NPI, the two top/ famous ones are factoring and graph isomorphism.

Comment: in short Shaefer thm sounds like a thm about SAT but is actually about a narrow language related to SAT which is apparently neither NP hard nor NP complete....? have long been looking for an "undergrad textbook" level presentation of Shaefer thm....

Comment: see also [wikipedia/ NPI / Ladners thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Schaefer's theorem applies only to a specific type of languages, those of the form $\mathrm{SAT}(S)$ for a finite set of relations over the Boolean domain or $\mathrm{CSP}(\Gamma)$ for a finite constraint language over the Boolean domain (the two notations are equivalent; see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer's_dichotomy_theorem) for a description). Any other language is not covered by the theorem, and the theorem has nothing to say about it. In particular, Schaefer's theorem doesn't say anything about your language $L$.

Comment: awesome but what exactly is SAT(S)? plz flesh this out more (although admittedly/ clearly few others think it necessary!)

Comment: This is explained very clearly in the Wikipedia page on Schaefer's theorem, from which I copied this notation.

Comment: but anyway still think this could all be explained better. "Schaefer defines a decision problem that he calls the Generalized Satisfiability problem". but apparently it is not so Generalized then....? eg why is the language he studies important, and not contrived? is it used anywhere else in CS other than his paper? what are the larger implications of this theorem, are there any or is it an isolated curiosity that seems to lead nowhere? could it conceivably somehow be used in a P vs NP attack or not? etc