# Does the following down-voted answer not answer the question "Why does Schaefer's theorem not prove that P=NP?"?

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, p-vs-np

Does the following [highly down-voted answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/162084/45563) not answer the question "[Why does Schaefer's theorem not prove that P=NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42544/45563)"? If not, why not?

> Marek, V. Wiktor. [*Introduction to Mathematics of
> Satisfiability*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6903).  Boca Raton; London; New-York: CRC Press, 2009,
> p. 310:
>
> > ***THEOREM 13.3 (Schaefer Theorem)***
> > *Let $Γ$ be a collection of Boolean tables. If one of conditions (1)–(6) below holds, then $CSP(Γ)$ is solvable in polynomial time.
> > Otherwise, it is NP-complete.*
>
> If P = NP-complete, the aforementioned conditions have no bearing on
> the runtime:
>
> > If the conditions hold, then $CSP(Γ)$ is solvable in P = NP-complete time.
> > Otherwise, $CSP(Γ)$ is solvable in P = NP-complete time.
>
> Which amounts to: "$CSP(Γ)$ is solvable in P = NP-complete time."
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[Review of *Introduction to Mathematics of Satisfiability* by M.
> I. Dekhtyar](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=299260):</sup>
>
> > <sup>Chapter 13 ends with a proof of
> > the well-known Shaefer dichotomy theorem which divides classes of
> > Boolean constraints into solvable in polynomial time and
> > NP-complete.</sup>